# 70's or 80's movie with flying bikes over a desert

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a film from my childhood. The scene I remember is a battle scene with flying motorcycles coming out of some sort of carrier, and they could fly or at least float down to the ground. The bikes had lots of flat panels to make them boxy and 80's style futuristic. They might have also had small wings, but I'm not sure. They didn't hover and looked like modified normal bikes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

WOPR's answer gave me "other videos to watch" and there it was. [Megaforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaforce)!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oops! I knew that already but thanks for reminding me to do it (2 days is such a long time!)

Comment: It's cool.  Sometimes I need to visit my profile, and review my questions in order to be reminded of questions I asked.  ;)

Answer (score 10):

I think you might be referring to Battlestar Galactica, which had flying motorcycles like the one you describe. Lift off at 2:56.

Clip here :

Comment: Not the one, but got me to the answer, so thanks! +1